# Unable to open ZFS pool because of incorrect pool configuration on Linux

Tags: linux, zfs, fedora20

After rebooting my ZFS pool was unable to open my main pool. The exact error that I'm getting is:
"The pool metadata is corrupted and the pool cannot be opened"

When I checked the zpool configuration using zpool status (from the recovery console), the configuration that it displayed was all wrong. The configuration listed several drives that I had just moved to other drives.

Currently the output of zpool status looks like this:

```
  pool: pool
 state: FAULTED
status: The pool metadata is corrupted and the pool cannot be opened.
action: Destroy and re-create the pool from
        a backup source.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-72
  scan: resilvered 511G in 12h39m with 0 erors on Sat Mar 14 06:14:34 2015
config:

        NAME                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        pool                              FAULTED      0     0     1  corrupted data
          raidz1-0                        ONLINE       0     0     8
            wwn-0x50014ee05943ce36-part4  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee05943ce36-part5  ONLINE       0     0     1
            wwn-0x50014ee05943ce36-part6  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee05943ce36-part7  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee05943ce36-part8  ONLINE       0     0     1
```

My question is, why does the configuration suddenly revert back to an old state after rebooting? (I checked with zpool status before rebooting and everything was fine and reported no errors). And how can I tell ZFS to change the configuration so that I can open the pool and get my data back?

I'm running Fedora 20, kernel 3.18.7-100

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It is a site for Programming questions, consider asking your question at http://unix.stackexchange.com/  or http://superuser.com/ Also, I think you should start with `zdb` - it should be able to determine what metadata was lost

Comment: Thank you for your answer myaut! I rebooted into a Fedora live cd, since zdb was not available in dracut recovery mode, but running zdb -l /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50014ee05943ce36-part4 lists 4 labels, all of them displaying the correct disk configuration the raidz pool

Comment: I will ask my question in unix.stackexchange.com, seems indeed like a better place :)